# Simulink - Store Variables inside a File

Tags: matlab, simulink, workspace

I know that typing `r=1` in the MATLAB command line let the variable `r` available for an open Simulink Model.

For complex models i can just make an S-Function and type everything in there.

But for simpler models, I wouldn't wish to type any command, nor keep any `.m` script aside, just the `.slx` file alone,  and still having a few variables `r` everywhere in the model, and available when I open it.

I dont remember if this is possible, how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simulink model window choose `File/Model properties/Model properties/Callbacks`:

[image: model properties window]

Now `r` can be used in the model:

[image: model window]